# Противопоставление при раздельном написании НЕ

Tags: орфография, частица-не

Противопоставление можно назвать **главным признаком раздельного написания частицы НЕ:** не далеко, а близко; не веселый, а грустный.

Противопоставление может быть **явным и скрытым,** вот пример скрытого противопоставления без союза А: Не небесам чужой отчизны – я песни родине слагал

Но противопоставление может просто **подразумеваться.** Если мы что-то отрицаем, то это что-то можно как-то мысленно обозначить или это возможно не всегда?

**И вопрос**: Всегда ли отрицание каким-либо образом  **связано** с противопоставлением?

Я возвращаюсь к ответу Грамоты.ру

> Вопрос № 298614  *Необязательно или не обязательно?*
>
> В зависимости от контекста возможно слитное или раздельное написание
>   (второе - при подчеркивании отрицания **либо при
>   противопоставлении**).

**Здесь противопоставление с отрицанием однозначно не связаны.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Противопоставление обязательно предполагает отрицание (*Я не врач, а фармацевт*), обратное неверно (*Я не врач* - никакого противопоставления, а отрицание налицо).

> вот пример скрытого противопоставления без союза А: Не небесам чужой отчизны – я песни родине слагал

Да, но здесь раздельное написание объясняется гораздо проще: слово *ненебеса* не существует в русском языке. Носитель языка ведь почти всегда может сказать - существует слово в языке или нет. Иностранцам труднее.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и за интересный пример. Вы врач? - Я не врач, а фармацевт. Это явное противопоставление. Но если не назвать свою специальность, то противопоставление все равно будет присутствовать, но в   «непроявленном» виде.  Вот  что я имела в виду.

Comment: Вряд ли с вами многие согласятся. Что значит "непроявленный" вид? Всё это очень умозрительно. Зачем усложнять - я просто отрицаю, что я врач.

Comment: В общем, Вы правы, что усложняю, для правописания это, как правило, не нужно. Да вот только  о каком противопоставлении говорит Грамота.ру в своем ответе, объясняя выбор обязательно/не обязательно?

Comment: *Вопрос № 298614 Необязательно или не обязательно?

В зависимости от контекста возможно слитное или раздельное написание (второе - при подчеркивании отрицания либо при противопоставлении)*


Например, "не обязательно, но желательно". Или "не обязательно, а по вашему усмотрению".

Comment: Решаю задачу. Не()обязательно иметь крылья, чтобы летать. Противопоставление не обозначено, отрицание могу подчеркнуть, а могу и не подчеркивать. Получается, что решение неоднозначное, можно писать наугад? Но люди на форумах постоянно задают такие вопрос, и им хочется не двойственности, а ясной КОНКРЕТИКИ.  А где ее взять?

Comment: Мы тут вместе с Грамотой только об этом и говорим: решение *неоднозначное*. Конкретики хотят люди, которые привыкли со школьной скамьи: только так и никак иначе! Но так бывает не всегда, ничего не поделаешь. Можно их утешить: ошибки не будет в любом случае.)

Comment: Последние лет 20 прослеживается тенденция: все чаще и чаще в подобных случаях предпочитают слитное написание. Например, читаем в "Словаре трудностей" издания 2003 года Розенталя: "НЕ СЛУЧАЙНО - только раздельно". Я сам пишу всегда только раздельно. Но слитное написание уже преобладает.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 3):

> Всегда ли отрицание каким-либо образом связано с противопоставлением?

Да нет же!

Когда Грамота.ру говорит "в зависимости от контекста", подразумевается, что следует отличать конструкции, усиливающие отрицание, от конструкций, подчеркивающих утвердительное значение.

**[Вопрос](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%20293251)** к Грамоте:

> Здравствуйте! Правильно ли написание частицы НЕ в следующем
>   предложении: *Жить нужно активно, иначе не интересно!*

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> Возможны оба варианта. При раздельном написании подчеркивается
>   отрицание признака. При слитном написании утверждается отрицательный
>   признак (=скучно).
>
> ---

Другими [учёными словами](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=76), то же, на бис:

> Пишущий должен отдавать себе отчет в том, что он хочет выразить:
>   отрицание признака — и тогда написать ***не*** отдельно от следующего слова
>   (напр.: *он не здоров, не важно, не редки случаи, не случайно, не
>   существенно, не удивительно, не демократическим путём*) или утверждение
>   признака — и тогда написать не слитно (ср.: он нездоров, нередки
>   случаи, неважно, неслучайно, несущественно, н*еудивительно,
>   недемократическим путем*). От выбора написания будет зависеть и
>   понимание написанного читающими.

Answer (score 1):

Раздельное написание НЕ может быть обусловлено как  противопоставлением, так и отрицанием, это две разные причины, и я не думаю, что одна из них главная.

> - Если в предложении есть или подразумевается противопоставление с союзом а.
> - Если частица не имеет значение отрицания.
>     ([Лампа](https://lampa.io/p/%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8-00000000d8573f987cea4c65181925c6))

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Правда, меня больше  интересует не само правописание, в "философская" сторона вопроса в общем виде: если это отрицание, то что именно мы отрицаем. При наличии противопоставления это ясно, а если явного противопоставления нет? (Кстати, эта тема в значительной степени касается прилагательных и образованных от них наречий). Давно меня интересовал этот вопрос, но ясное понимание отрицания в языке так и не сложилось.

Comment: @Sharon С философской точки зрения, мир слов не духотомичен, отрицание чего-то одного не всегда означает утверждение чего-то другого.

Comment: Речь идет о роли отрицания в мире слов. При отрицании мы ОБРАЩАЕМСЯ к какой-то системе классификации, и в пределах этой конкретной системы  дихотомичность вполне себе применима (то есть, наверное, применима)